# Want to remove objects that are before specific value

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native

---

```
const array = [{
    id: "U",
    T: "001"
  },
  {
    id: "R",
    T: "002"
  },
  {
    id: "U",
    T: "003"
  },
  {
    id: "R",
    T: "004"
  },
  {
    id: "U",
    T: "005"
  },
]
```

Above array can have multiple objects with `id: 'R'` and i want to ignore all objects that are before `id: 'R'`.

Expected:

```
const array = [
{ id: "U", 
T: "005"}]
```

Can someone please help with this

Comment: What if there is no id of R in the array?

Comment: Please accept an answer as the solution if it solves the problem

Answer (score 2):

- Using [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), get the list of ids
- Using [`Array#lastIndexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/lastIndexOf), get the index of the last occurrence of the id "R"
- Using [`Array#splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice), get the target sub-array following this index

```js
const array = [ { id: "U", T: "001" }, { id: "R", T: "002" }, { id: "U", T: "003" }, { id: "R", T: "004" }, { id: "U", T: "005" } ];

const ids = array.map(({ id }) => id);
const index = ids.lastIndexOf("R") + 1;
const res = array.splice(index);

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Thank you Majed, 

If i have same scenario but instead of index i want to do it based on value from object, ex:

const array = [ {b:'0', id: "U", T: "001" }, 
{ b:'3',id: "R", T: "004" },
{ b:'1',id: "R", T: "002" },
{ b:'2',id: "U", T: "003" }, 
{ b:'4',id: "U", T: "005" } ];

in this case as well i want object after last "R" but based on `b`

Comment: @PratikKumar can you explain more what you mean by "based on b"? What would be the output of the above?

Answer (score 1):

Agree with all the above answers, but why do we go with the **map**, **slice**, **reverese** and all. We can simply use just a loop instead of those as below. Considering time as well, if the array length increases the combination of any of the map, reverse, slice, splice takes much time

```js
const array = [{
    id: "U",
    T: "001"
  },
  {
    id: "R",
    T: "002"
  },
  {
    id: "U",
    T: "003"
  },
  {
    id: "R",
    T: "004"
  },
  {
    id: "U",
    T: "005"
  },
];

let newArr = [];

for(let i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
if(array[i].id === 'R') break;
else newArr.push(array[i])
}
console.log(newArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Reverse array, Find the index of first R, slice array...

```js
const array = [{
    id: "U",
    T: "001"
  },
  {
    id: "R",
    T: "002"
  },
  {
    id: "U",
    T: "003"
  },
  {
    id: "R",
    T: "004"
  },
  {
    id: "U",
    T: "005"
  }
]

const cheak = (element) => element.id === "R"


console.log(array.reverse().slice(0, array.findIndex(cheak)).reverse());
```

Comment: I think OP wants everything before the last occurrence of id: R to be removed, this just finds the first index.

Comment: @Undo You are right, so just reverse the array ;)

Answer (score 0):

```js
const array = [
  {
    id: "U",
    T: "001",
  },
  {
    id: "R",
    T: "002",
  },
  {
    id: "U",
    T: "003",
  },
  {
    id: "R",
    T: "004",
  },
  {
    id: "U",
    T: "005",
  },
];

/**
 * 
 * @param {array} data
 * @param {string} id  
 * @returns The results you want
 */

function getData(data, id) {
  let lastIndex = 0;

  Array.from(data).forEach((item, index) => {
    if (item.id === id.trim("")) {
      lastIndex = index;
    }
  });

  const result = data.slice(lastIndex + 1);

  return result;
}


console.log(getData(array, "R"));
/*
* Result:
* [{ id: 'U', T: '005' } ]
*/
```